# Should removing of tags from question Title be encouraged?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

When some one edits a question which involves just removing tags in title, should it be considered as an Improvement of the question and be approved ? or can the edit be rejected as too minor ?

Comment: That decision always come down to the question "is there something else to fix?". If the answer is "no", accept it. If the answer is "yes, but not much" improve and accept. If the answer is "heck yeah, he missed most of the problems" reject, or improve and reject.

Comment: If "tags" are natural part of sentence, removing them might actually be a bad idea. "How to prevent *something* when I *do something* on my PHP arrays?" would lose meaning if someone would try to reword it to avoid arrays and PHP in title.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The answer to the original question is: "No, please don't include tags in titles". Answers to _this_ question may be "Why not? Go ahead, accept suggested edits which remove tags in titles" or "Of course, reject this kind of suggested edits as too minor", both compatible with the answer to the former question.

Comment: @Molot Tags in title are more like: "PHP: How to prevent something when I do something?", or "[PHP] [something] How do I prevent something else?"

Comment: @DanielDaranas It's not an exact duplicate. But with the general consensus that tags should not be in titles (unless they form a natural part of the sentence) and the multitude of questions regarding what constitutes "too minor", I'd hardly think adding an answer here will contribute much more.